# Extracting float numbers from file using python

Tags: python

I have .txt file which looks like:

```
[ -5.44339373e+00  -2.77404404e-01   1.26122094e-01   9.83589873e-01
   1.95201179e-01  -4.49866890e-01  -2.06423297e-01   1.04780491e+00]
 [  4.34562117e-01  -1.04469577e-01   2.83633101e-01   1.00452355e-01   -7.12572469e-01  -4.99234705e-01  -1.93152897e-01   1.80787567e-02]
```

I need to extract all floats from it and put them to list/array

What I've done is this:

```
A = []
for line in open("general.txt", "r").read().split(" "):
    for unit in line.split("]", 3):
        A.append(list(map(lambda x: str(x), unit.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(" "))))
```

but `A` contains elements like `['']` or even worse `['3.20973096e-02\n']`. These are all strings, but I need floats. How to do that?

Comment: "A contains elements like ['']" - then please provide a better example file.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo what do you mean a better example?

Comment: You can `str.strip` the line before you `str.split`, and either `filter` out the empty elements or use `str.split()` (note: **no arguments**) to group consecutive whitespace.

Comment: @Xxx it seems like the problem with reading the example file with your example code is that the example file doesn't actually look like that. There are no `'` characters in it for example. If you're just guessing what your file actually looks like it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more precise way you can use regex for split the lines :

```
>>> s="""[ -5.44339373e+00  -2.77404404e-01   1.26122094e-01   9.83589873e-01
...    1.95201179e-01  -4.49866890e-01  -2.06423297e-01   1.04780491e+00]
...  [  4.34562117e-01  -1.04469577e-01   2.83633101e-01   1.00452355e-01   -7.12572469e-01  -4.99234705e-01  -1.93152897e-01   1.80787567e-02] """
>>> print re.split(r'[\s\[\]]+',s)
['', '-5.44339373e+00', '-2.77404404e-01', '1.26122094e-01', '9.83589873e-01', '1.95201179e-01', '-4.49866890e-01', '-2.06423297e-01', '1.04780491e+00', '4.34562117e-01', '-1.04469577e-01', '2.83633101e-01', '1.00452355e-01', '-7.12572469e-01', '-4.99234705e-01', '-1.93152897e-01', '1.80787567e-02', '']
```

And in this case that you have the data in file you can do :

```
import re
print re.split(r'[\s\[\]]+',open("general.txt", "r").read())
```

If you want to get ride of the empty strings in leading and trailing you can just use a list comprehension :

```
>>> print [i for i in re.split(r'[\s\[\]]*',s) if i]
['-5.44339373e+00', '-2.77404404e-01', '1.26122094e-01', '9.83589873e-01', '1.95201179e-01', '-4.49866890e-01', '-2.06423297e-01', '1.04780491e+00', '4.34562117e-01', '-1.04469577e-01', '2.83633101e-01', '1.00452355e-01', '-7.12572469e-01', '-4.99234705e-01', '-1.93152897e-01', '1.80787567e-02']
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a regular expression?

```
>>> import re
>>> e = r'(\d+\.\d+e?(?:\+|-)\d{2}?)'
>>> results = re.findall(e, your_string)
['5.44339373e+00',
 '2.77404404e-01',
 '1.26122094e-01',
 '9.83589873e-01',
 '1.95201179e-01',
 '4.49866890e-01',
 '2.06423297e-01',
 '1.04780491e+00',
 '4.34562117e-01',
 '1.04469577e-01',
 '2.83633101e-01',
 '1.00452355e-01',
 '7.12572469e-01',
 '4.99234705e-01',
 '1.93152897e-01',
 '1.80787567e-02']
```

Now, these are the matched *strings*, but you can easily convert them to floats:

```
>>> map(float, re.findall(e, your_string))
[5.44339373,
 0.277404404,
 0.126122094,
 0.983589873,
 0.195201179,
 0.44986689,
 0.206423297,
 1.04780491,
 0.434562117,
 0.104469577,
 0.283633101,
 0.100452355,
 0.712572469,
 0.499234705,
 0.193152897,
 0.0180787567]
```

Note, the regular expression might need some tweaking, but its a good start.

Comment: And to capture the minus sign in some of the values, the regex could be modified to `e = r'(-*\d+\.\d+e?(?:\+|-)\d{2}?)'`

Comment: How to add to the regular expression @ and ^?

Answer (score 0):

1. let's slurp the file

   ```
   content = open('data.txt').read()
   ```
2. split on `']'`

   ```
   logical_lines = content.split(']')
   ```
3. strip the `'['` and the other stuff

   ```
   logical_lines = [ll.lstrip(' \n[') for ll in logical_lines]
   ```
4. convert to floats

   ```
   lol = [map(float,ll.split()) for ll in logical_lines]
   ```

Sticking it all in a one-liner

```
lol=[map(float,l.lstrip(' \n[').split()) for l in open('data.txt').read().split(']')]
```

I've tested it on the exemplar data we were given and it works...